# How to store & retrieve specific part of XML tree?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a **TreeView** that binds to an **XML document**. each **TreeViewItem** has a **CheckBox** (Like Windows Directory Tree but with a checkBox inside each item).

for example for this tree:

[image]

I need to save the path of selected item from root to leaf (yellow item) and retrieve this path from the original tree.

So what is the best solution to **store** and **retrieve** the checked path of this XML tree?

Note that I need the ability to **compare** this path too!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via XPATh you can try something like this I hope this is what you are talking about..

```
string xpath = null;
XmlNode configNode = configDom.DocumentElement;
// collect selected nodes in node list
XmlNodeList nodeList =
configNode.SelectNodes(@"//*[@status='checked']");

//MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(nodeList.Count));

// loop through nodelist
foreach(XmlNode myNode in nodeList)
{
xpath = GetPathFromNode(myNode); // get node path
xpath = xpath + "\\" + myNode.InnerText.ToString(); // complete path
string
}
```

Comment: I need to store & retrieve the path to the selectedItem!

Comment: When you say path are you meaning file Path ...?? please clarify

Comment: Thanks. but I need to create & store a new xml base on original xml schema but only contain the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a node using the XmlDocument, take a look at [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx)

Comment: I saved the original XML file and need to save the path of selectedItems. and from this two argument regenerate the stared Xml.

Comment: I updated my answer let me know if this is what you are looking for if not I will provide a better solution..thanks